# How can i iterate over objects that already inside a database and update a field?

Tags: database, rest, webapi

I'm building a RESTful API that will show all of my assets/investments.
I want to show in each asset how much precent of the totalValue of the portolio this asset is. I want totalValue to be something dynamic therefore with each new asset created it adds up the (realTimePrice * amount) to the totalValue.

My question is: Once i finished to populate the database and the totalValue is calculated, How can i run on each object in the database and run setPercentage() ?

For example:

"name": Bitcoin
"ticker": BTC-USD
"percentage": 20

[image: How totalValue is being summed up with each object that inserted to the database]

[image]

This is how i seed my dataBase:

```
package assets.asset;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;


@Configuration

class SeedDB {

@Bean
CommandLineRunner initDatabase(DataBase repository) {
    return args -> {

        repository.save(new Asset("", "",, , "Crypto"));
        repository.save(new Asset("", "",, , "Crypto"));
        repository.save(new Asset("", "",, , "Crypto"));
        repository.save(new Asset("", "",, , "Stock"));
        repository.save(new Asset("", "",, , "Stock"));
        repository.save(new Asset("", "",, , "Stock"));
        
    };
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a scalable design at all. A single calculation is being done several times over. Imagine you had a table of 1 million of these values and you need to fill up the portfolio percentage for all of them, you would essentially be recalculating the total asset value a million times over. This value could instead be cached and updated as and when a new field is added.

In my opinion, the percentage of the asset value in relation to the portfolio, should not even be stored in the database. The reason is that, this value requires frequent updates. For example, everytime we add one asset, we will have to update the percentage for all the values.

This is a value that should be calculated upon request.

We could store a specific value in the database called 'Total Asset Value'. This would hold the relevant information.
Then everytime an op is done to add a new number, we can have a Service that would do

```
public void setTotalValue() {
    TotalValue+=BigDecimal.valueOf(amount);
    repository.save(totalValue); // this line can be however you want to persist your data
}
```

The idea is to add to the total value everytime you add a new asset and then when we want to calculate the total value, we can do something like,

```
public Map<Asset, BigDecimal> getTotalPercentages(List<Asset> assets) {
    for (asset : asset) {
        map.put(asset, asset.value/totalValue);
    }
    return map;
}
```

This would give you accurate data dynamically and saves on the extra time for insertion to db.

EDIT: after being given some context in the comments, i have re-did another solution.

We could simply have a variable totalValue that grows everytime you add an asset in the seeding stage and at the end of the seeding, you could iterate through all assets and set the percentage for each of them.

```
int totalValue = 0;
String[] types = new String[]{"Crypto", "Stock"};
for (int i = 0; i < NUM_OF_DESIRED_ASSETS; i++) {
    Random r = new Random();
    int value = r.nextInt(10);
    int index = r.nextInt(2);
    repository.save(new Asset("", "",value, , types[index]));   

    totalValue+=value; 
}

for (asset : assets) {
    asset.setPercentage(asset.value/totalValue);
    repository.save(asset);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer :)

I agree it is not a scalable design, but the max number of assets that i supposed to hold is 50-70.

" everytime we add one asset, we will have to update the percentage for all the values. "
-  I want to calculate the totalValue after all assets has been inserted and then run over all the assets and use setPercentage() which will have to use totalValue after it already been calculated.

" This is a value that should be calculated upon request. "
I thought about it, is there a way to create a GET of (/assets/percentage) and perform that setPercentage() ?

Comment: sure thats right - option 1, you could have a GET endpoint /assets/totalValue that retrieves the total value of all assets. then, in your frontend, you could do the calculation, amount/totalValue.
option 2 is to have a GET assets/percentage/{asset_id} as you mentioned, and send the asset id over. Then, calculate the percentage on the backend and return it. 
personally option 1, sounds better since the calculation could really be done by client or by server, and we save on one lookup to db for the asset information. 
either works though!

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I still don't understand how should i implement that.

I want that in my RESTController when users will ask for assets/percentage
it will run setPercentage for all assets.

Comment: I still think the best way to go about it is from the SeedDB class after all objects are created and totalValue is set then i need to somehow run setPercentage() over all the objects that is already in the database.

I will say again i know it is not optimal but i'm just gonna use 50-70 assets max and gonna block users POST methods so they can't add assets only me, they can only watch.

Comment: the context makes things a bit clearer, thanks for that - edited my answer to include new approach. hope it makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

The reply from 'berlin' helped a lot.
Once i finished populate the database i just added the following to the SeedDB class :

```
            for (Asset asset : repository.findAll())
            {
            asset.percentage = asset.setPercentage();
            repository.save(asset);
            }
```

I have been trying several ideas including trying to use a @PutMapping that will triger setPercentage() but did not understand how to perform it on all assets and collect them and return them.

Anyway problem is solved :)